# Atmospheric Web Map Service data for South America and Brazil

Tags: noaa, data, brazil

I'm working in a environmental project in Brazil and I need to create, if possible, a map service to show atmospheric conditions.

I'm looking for a WMS source to show cloud and another atmospheric data in Brazil. Something similar to the map from this link:

https://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/imagery/interactive-maps/the-world-real-time

Does anyone know a WMS that can provide me with this data?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for related docs and the used webservices from your map link, you should be able to access the NOAA Tile Services on ArcGIS:

https://satellitemaps.nesdis.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/MERGEDGC_current/ImageServer/tile/7/66/38

https://gis.nnvl.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/TRUE/TRUE_current/ImageServer/tile/7/65/33

https://satellitemaps.nesdis.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ABI10_current/ImageServer/tile/3/4/0

These are not WMS but an average GIS client should be able to support (ArcGIS) Tile Services.

Please make sure to follow the indicated restrictions and citation notes from their page https://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/real-time-imagery/interactive-maps/how-use-the-interactive-satellite-maps.